# Did not find bean NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I try to get bean, by using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. But I receive: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'newsController' is defined`

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:conf/Spring_Config.xml");

NewsController newsController = (NewsController) 
applicationContext.getBean("newsController");
```

In *xml*:

```
  <bean id="newsController" class="NewsController"/>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you go with xml based configuration instead of annotation based config? I am asking because I feel annotation based config is less error prone.

Comment: I think your classpath declaration is wrong `classpath*:conf/Spring_Config.xml`. Why have you used `*`. It might be the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add full path to the bean class tag

class=com.foo.NewsController